# WinError 10060 Error when trying to connect to remote server using Python PySFTP module

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I am trying to connect to a remote server and list files inside a path using the below code:

```
import pysftp

myHostname = "myhostname.com"
myPort = <someportnumber>
myUsername = "<valid username>"
myPassword = "<valid password>"

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts= cnopts, port=myPort) as sftp:
    print("Connection succesfully established ... ")

    sftp.chdir('/logs/dev')

    # Obtain structure of the remote directory
    directory_structure = sftp.listdir_attr()

    # Print data
    for attr in directory_structure:
        print(attr.filename, attr)
```

But when I am running it, It is unable to establish a connection. It's throwing below exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/611841191/Documents/SFTP File Download/SFTPFileDownload.py", line 11, in <module>
    with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts= cnopts, port=myPort) as sftp:
  File "C:\Users\611841191\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._start_transport(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\611841191\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 176, in _start_transport
    self._transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
  File "C:\Users\611841191\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 415, in __init__
    raise SSHException(
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Unable to connect to <myhostname.com>: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Can anyone help me out with why this exception is being thrown because I tried with other remote servers and the code seems to be working fine for them? The code is throwing exception for one particular remote server only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code cannot connect somewhere using some protocol (SFTP in this case), the first thing to test is, whether you can connect using the same protocol using any existing GUI/commandline client from the same machine that runs your code.

If that does not work either, you do not have a programming question, but a simple network connectivity problem.

If you need a help resolving the problem, please go to [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).